# How to simulate the distance to the nearest neighbor in a poisson process?

Tags: python, nearest-neighbor, poisson

I am new to the topic and I have problems with the simulation of this problem:
In a study, the trees in a certain region of a forest were counted, a total of 630 trees were counted, of which 91 are lollipops and the rest are pines. If the average distance to the nearest neighbor for pines is 1,990m and for lollipops 5,080m, plot two simulations of the distributions of these trees if they were found in an area of ​​200×50 m2.
I have only been able to do this, but it is not what the problem asks for, because I do not know how to apply the concept of nearest neighbors.

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.stats import poisson,uniform
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
lam=630/10000
area=200*50
simulaciones=100
simlist=np.zeros(100)
for i in range(simulaciones):
    N=poisson.rvs(lam*area)
    PuntoX=uniform.rvs(0,200,size=N)
    PuntoY=uniform.rvs(0,50,size=N)
    PuntosDentro=sum((PuntoX-1.990)**2+(PuntoY-1.990)**2<=1.990**2)
    simlist[i]=PuntosDentro
print(np.mean(simlist))
plt.scatter(PuntoX,PuntoY)
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

The average distance to the nearest neighbor can be used to estimate the number of trees of  given type per m². Suppose that the for a given type of tree, the average distance to the nearest neighbor is r, then it's reasonable to consider there is one tree of that type in a circle of radius r. So, an estimation for the number of trees of that type per m² is 1/(pi * r²).

The fact there is a fixed number of trees in a given area with high probability, makes Poisson a good distribution for the number of trees in a given area. For instance, with this supposition, the probability that there are k trees in an area A would be ((A/(pi * r²))^k) * e^(-A/(pi * r²)) / k!.